# Typescript React component not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a `Cars` component that will have multiple `Car` components inside. I have some checks to make sure the `Car[]` is not undefined or null. But `Car` is not being rendered

console log of carobj is: `Object { id: 5, year: 2009, make: "honda", model: "civic", price: 18000, person_id: 1, created_at: "2022-03-12T05:56:18.526Z", updated_at: "2022-03-12T05:56:18.526Z" }`

just before I pass the data into the `car` component

cars.tsx:

```
import {car, Car} from './car';
interface cars {
    cars?: car[];
}
function Cars (props: cars) {
    return (
        <div className="carcontainer">
            <h2>cars container</h2>
            {props.cars && props.cars?.length > 0 && props.cars!!.map((carobj: car, idx) => {
                console.log(carobj);
                let {year, make, model, price, person_id } = carobj;
                <Car year={year} make={make} model={model} price={price} person_id={person_id} key={idx} />
                // <Car {...carobj} key={idx}/>
            })}
            </div>
    )
}
export default Cars;
```

and my car.tsx component:

```
export interface car {
    year: number,
    make:string,
    model: string,
    price: number,
    person_id: number,
}

export function Car (props: car) {
    console.log(props.year);
    return (
        <div className="car">
            <h3>
                car:{props.year} {props.make} {props.model} {props.price}
                </h3>
            </div>
    )
}
```

the consolelog of `props.year` inside the `Car` doesn't show up in the console.

I've tried spreading the props and also explicitly passing the props in.

No errors show up in the reactapp or in the console. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Nothing is getting rendered cause ur not returning the car component. return <Car .../>

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-t4ywyw?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: The `Cars` component is receiving `cars[]` as a prop. Is prop being passed dynamically after an API call, the parent component should be passing it as a state so that rerender happens.